# How can I delete current session in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I'm using Google Chrome and want to delete the current session data on the fly. I can do this on Firefox with the web developer extension, but Chrome doesn't seem to have the same option in their webdev extension. So how can I do this?

I realize that session data is stored on the server side and tracked in the browser with cookies. So really, I think what I want to do is delete cookies that are set to live for the session lifetime. Is there a way to do THAT in Chrome? "Delete browsing data" lets me delete all cookies from within a certain time period (for example, the last hour), but that could delete OTHER cookies on the site that I don't want to erase. I just want to delete the cookie being used to track my current session.

**To be even more clear:** In Firefox, with the web programmer extension installed, I can log into a site, choose "clear session cookies" and just the PHPSESSID cookie is erased. However, other cookies for that domain are not erased or otherwise touched. I want to be able to do this exact same functionality in Chrome.

Thanks y'all...

Comment: I define session data as Any data stored during the session. You need to state what data you want to delete rather than what you do not want to delete. The one data store Chrome does not delete using "clear browsing data" is the "Local Storage" folder data, you have to do this manually, do not delete anything in there that starts with "chrome-extension"

Comment: In re-thinking my question, I realize that session data is stored on the server side and tracked in the browser with cookies. So really, I think what I want to do is delete cookies that are set to live for the session lifetime. Is there a way to do THAT in Chrome? "Delete browsing data" lets me delete all cookies from within a certain time period (for example, the last hour), but that could delete OTHER cookies on the site that I don't want to erase. I just want to delete the cookie used to track my current session. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please edit your question instead. (That will also bump it back to the homepage, so folks will actually see your question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity: You want to be able to ONLY delete the cookies of a specific site OR even just single cookies of a given site, right?

There's a few extensions that let you do stuff like that.

If you just want to delete all cookies for the site opened in the current tab, check out [Remove Cookies For Site](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lmfdblomdpkcniknaenceeogpgepocmm).

If you want more options, like editing, deleting only certain cookies of a site, [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) might be your extension. You'll get a menu for all cookies of the current site:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to delete the session cookie(s) for a given site and no other cookies. I edited my question and added a bit to the end to clarify that.

Comment: Then "Edit This Cookie" is your choice. I took a screenshot and added it to my original answer. I think that's what your looking for.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know if this is what you were looking for but anyway, a similar functionality is built right into chrome:

`Right-click -> Inspect element`.

Go to resources tab and enable tracking if you haven't already.

Now scroll down the left hand sidebar thingy until you see `cookies`, under it click your domain name and to delete a cookie just `right-click` on its name and `delete`

Comment: The `developer tools` can also be opened by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+J`.

Comment: `F12` also opens the chrome's `DevTools`

Comment: Cookies aren't session data in chrome (which can persist despite clearing cookies), so that doesn't help..

Comment: In my chrome it's the Application tab and cookies are under Storage

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following procedure in Chrome:

1. Hit `F12` or open the contextual menu (right click), then "Inspect element"
2. Go to the `Application` tab
3. On the right sidebar menu, go to `Application > Clear storage`
4. Uncheck everything but `Local and session storage`
5. Scroll to the very down and click `Clear site data`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't clear session cookies for the current tab, probably by design.

So try going to another tab before clearing. This might also be useful in helping users that see outdated session data on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try downloading [Web Developer for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm)?

If you go to the cookies section of the popup, you can selectively delete only "Session Cookies".

Answer (score 0):

For me,was

> by click on **lock icon** select **Cookies** then choose **Remove**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo?hl=en&authuser=0) chrome extension clears the session cookies quite easily.

Steps:

1. Click **Session** quick filter
2. Click Select All checkbox
3. Click Delete

[image]